# Escape commas inside values while writing spark dataframes to csv

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `df.write("csv")` for writing my value set in Apache Spark.

By default it writes the values like :

`1,abcded,"qwe,rr"` i.e wraps in double quotes when there is a comma inside the value.

However, I want to escape the comma like `qwe\\,rr` and not get it wrapped by double quotes.
Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) from databricks you can set the `quoteMode` property to `None` as shown below to do this.

```
 df.write.option("quoteMode", "None").csv("/path/to/target")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val updatedDf = df.withColumn(
   "<column-name>", regexp_replace(col("<column-name>"), ",", "\\\\\\\\,"))
```